# Remapping <Esc> in MacVim angers Vim itself

Tags: vim, remapping

I have the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Esc> :noh<Cr>
```

This works fine in MacVim. Whenever I open Vim itself, its "command bar" starts off with:

```
.2c
```

For what it's worth, when enter to execute the command, Vim complains with `E16: Invalid range`.

It's a minor annoyance, but how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: @peth I have not! :( I temporarily gave up trying to do this — I hop in and out of Vim very frequently, so this issue was becoming very annoying. I would definitely appreciate that bounty. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping <kbd>Esc</kbd> is always a little tricky and generally inviting this kind of trouble, even though it *shouldn't* happen.

The "canonical" method for your mapping is:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohlsearch<CR><C-l>
```

That way <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> (which normally redraws your screen) will stop highlighting *and* redraw the screen.

---

I think I've found out what happens, but I still have no solution. I assumed Vim received a string containing an `<ESC>` and "2c", so I used the following mapping to make it visible:

```
nnoremap <Esc> :"
```

It resulted in the following prompt on startup:

```
:"[>0;261;0c
```

Which means something sent `<ESC>[>0;261;0c` on startup. Now looking up the original [`xterm` control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), we find that:

```
ESC [         Control Sequence Introducer (CSI is 0x9b)
```

and

> CSI > *P s* c
>
> Send Device Attributes (Secondary DA).
>
> *P s* = 0 or omitted → request the
>   terminal’s identification code. The
>   response depends on the **decTerminalID**
>   resource setting. It should apply only
>   to VT220 and up, but *xterm* extends
>   this to VT100.
>
> → CSI > *P p* ; *P v* ; *P c c*
>
> where *P p* denotes the terminal type
>
> *P p* = 0 → ‘‘VT100’’.
>   *P p* = 1 → ‘‘VT220’’.
>
> and *P v* is the firmware
>   version (for *xterm*, this was
>   originally the XFree86 patch number,
>   starting with 95). In a DEC terminal,
>   *P c* indicates the ROM cartridge
>   registration number and is always
>   zero.

So in my case something sends `CSI >` with *P p* = 0 (→ terminal type VT100), *P v* = 261 (→ my `xterm` version), and *P c* = 0.

Still I have no idea where it comes from or how to stop it. My best guess is that some information exchange between the terminal and Vim fails and something is bugged up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but adding this to my `.vimrc` didn't resolve the issue. Rats! I'm using Snow Leopard.

Comment: Awesome research. +1 From me. Because I wasn't the person who "funded" the bounty, I'm going to wait until tomorrow to mark your answer as correct, assuming no one else answers.

Comment: \*GASP\* I hadn't noticed that you were *also* the one who placed the bounty!! I feel like an idiot! In my defense, I had already marked your answer as the solution earlier today — before this revelation...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for some terminal vim receives [>0;261;0c that way. And the last "c" makes vim start painful, but I have found easy trick for skipping first "c" at startup:

```
nnoremap c :nunmap c<Cr>
```